# How to find a new browser window using webdriver io?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am writing CoffeeScript tests using Webdriver.io and mocha.

I cannot resize the window in Google Chrome browser. I was told that the **window.resizeTo(width, height)** command can only resize the window if the window was created by the window.open () command. However, if I create a new window with the **window.open()** command, I don't know how to find this new window using Webdriver IO. Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('Sorts the inventory in asc order of price and adds element to cart', async () => {
   await browser.url("https://www.google.com")
   await browser.setWindowSize(200,100)
});
```

use serwindowsize if you are using wdio v7 and for new window use:

```
await browser.newWindow('https://webdriver.io', { windowName: 'WebdriverIO window', windowFeature: 'width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1', })
```

Comment: These commands resize the screen in the Mozilla browser, but in the chrome browser they cannot resize the screen (there is no error, but the size does not change). At least in my tests. I need the screen size to change in chrome browser. I would be very grateful if you can help me find the answer.

Comment: The code was tested in latest chrome and it works fine could you add a link to reproducible example, link github or something

Comment: The problem is solved, I reinstalled the web driver and the error disappeared.